# How to check if a user has granted a certain set of permissions to my PHP app?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

Based on [this question](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7687014/how-to-check-if-user-has-granted-a-certain-set-of-permissions-to-my-app-using-t), is there a way to check if a user has granted a certain set of permissions to an app using PHP based Facebook SDK?
I've browsed the API but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Please [see my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37130185/281087) to check using facebook-php-sdk-v4-5.0.0

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
$permissions = $facebook->api("/me/permissions");
```

then use the if to check which permission you need

EX:

```
if (array_key_exists('publish_stream', $permissions['data'][0])) {
    postToWall();
} else {
    //Does not have permission
}
```

If you are using FQL

```
$perms = $facebook->api(array(
    "method" => "fql.query",
    "query" => "SELECT read_stream,offline_access,publish_stream FROM permissions WHERE uid=me()"
        ));
echo "<ul>";
foreach ($perms[0] as $k => $v) {
    echo "<li>";
    if ($v === "1") {
        echo "<strong>$k</strong> permission is granted.";
    } else {
        echo "<strong>$k</strong> permission is not granted.";
    }
    echo "</li>";
}
```

http://www.masteringapi.com/tutorials/how-to-check-if-user-has-certian-permission-facebook-api/22/

Comment: FQL code fragment code style looks ugly. Could you please reformat it with correct block indentation. It is usual easy to edit your code in your preferred editor than you just need to add 4 spaces indentation to the whole code fragment and copy/paste it here.

Answer (score 2):

This also worked for me, in cases when I didn't have an access token, but had the user's ID:

```
$isGranted = $facebook->api(array(
    "method"    => "users.hasAppPermission",
    "ext_perm"   => "publish_stream",
    "uid"       => $facebook_id
));
```