# facebook->getUser() return 0 if user grants basic permission but not extended permissions

Tags: facebook, facebook-login

i do login like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function fbLogin(){
FB.init({ appId: 'FB_ID', 
status: true, 
cookie: true,
xfbml: true,
channelUrl: 'https://fbapps.promplac.si/channel.php',
oauth: true});
FB.login(function(response) {
if (response.authResponse) {
document.getElementById("korak1").submit();
} else {}
}, {scope:'email, user_likes, user_birthday, user_location, user_interests, photo_upload, publish_stream'});  
}
</script>
```

And this is working normally

When user grants normal permissions, but not extended my form get submitted, but when i ask in php: facebook->getUser() it returns 0.

Is the same user uses my app again, and again he doesnt grant extended parmission, i normaly get userid by facebook->getUser().

What is wrong?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8479076/880719

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A the end i solved it from frontend end, i check if user is logged and then send access token to php.

some code example:

```
document.getElementById("accesstoken").value=FB.getAuthResponse()['accessToken'];
```